# A recursive function in Angular html document

Tags: html, angular, recursion, tree, diagram

I need to build a diagram visualy basicaly a family tree:
[this is what i need :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjt1F.png)
from an object array that looks like this

```
[{
Id:1,
child:[
       {id:2,
        child:[
               {id:4,
                child:[]}]
        },
        {id:3,
        child:[]}
        ]
}]
```

I think my only option to generate the tree is using recursive function in the html component.
Is it even possible to make a recursive function using ngfor and ng-template? And how can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really don’t want to have your recursive logic inside your template. That belongs in your component. Maybe have a look at the Angular Material CDK tree component?

Comment: I can't see any suitableoption except recursion. It should look like a family tree, you know Granny is on the top, mother and father below her, etc.

Comment: Something like this? https://material.angular.io/cdk/tree/overview

Comment: no, more like this https://cs.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soubor:Family_Tree_of_Ra%C3%BAl_Castro.jpg

Comment: ah right... also that kinda presentation? In the end, a tree is a tree - so functionally the tree link I gave should get you to a tree-like data structure. To get it to that format - I think you'll probably have to do some nifty css yourself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case anyone needs to solve exactly the same problem

```
    <ul>
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="Recursion; context:{ list: List}"
      ></ng-container>
    </ul>



<ng-template #Recursion let-list="list">
      <li *ngFor="let item of list">
        <a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
        <ul *ngIf="item.child.length > 0">
          <ng-container
            *ngTemplateOutlet="Recursion; context:{ list: item.child }"
          ></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
```